# Recursidad Yii2 no funciona

Tags: php, yii2, recursión, yii

estoy tratando de implementar recursividad en yii2, aplicando el render, pero al parecer no funciona cuando despliego en la vista. Cuando realizo un echo de la variable "filterMin" o "filterMax", me muestra el resultado. Pero cuando hago un echo en la vista aparece NULL. ¿Alguien sabe por qué sucede esto?

```
 public function actionCategoriaDetalle($id, $filterMin = NULL, $filterMax=NULL){
    $this->layout = 'main';
    if($filterMin == NULL and $filterMax == NULL){    
        $this->actionCategoriaDetalle($id,100,200);
    }
    return $this->render('categoria_detalle', [
                'maximo'=>$filterMax,
                'minimo'=>$filterMin]);
}
```

Comment: no es necesaria la recursividad, por lo que veo quieres darle un valor a unas variables cuando sean null.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no necesitas hacer un proceso recursivo ya que no existe la necesidad de volver a llamar al método, que dicho sea el caso no es una práctica correcta utilizando el patrón MVC ni como principio de programación. Para su caso lo puede resolver de la siguientes manera:

```
<?php   

public function actionCategoriaDetalle($id, $filterMin = 100, $filterMax = 200) 
{
    $this->layout = 'main';
    return $this->render('categoria_detalle', [
            'maximo' => $filterMax,
            'minimo' => $filterMin
    ]);
}
```

Como esta haciendo una llamada a la acción `categoria-detalle` con valores opcionales `$filterMin` y `$filterMax` lo que hace es declarar los valores por defecto como los necesita si el navegador no los envía. Si el navegador los envía obviamente sobre-escribirá los que tiene por defecto.